# C# Show dialog over another dialog in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I have a winforms application (C#) and in one of my forms, i have a dialog that adds some entity to a datagrid in the main form. In this dialog, i have validations that if they are invalid, those errors are showed in a new dialog.. my problem is that this error dialog shows on the back of the first dialog... how can i do to show the errors dialog over the first dialog?

My form is something like this:

```
MainForm----DataGridButton---Add entity---> OpenDialog1 ---> OpenDialog1-Validation --- On Errors ---> OpenDialogErrors (This dialog is showed on the "back" of OpenDialog1)
```

The OpenDialog1 shows the OpenDialogErrors like this:

```
FrmErrors err = new FrmErrors();
err.ShowDialog(this.MdiParent);
```

Comment: It's not, is set to false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to show OpenDialogErrors this way:

```
err.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: That's what i want!.. how this works? why "this" makes show it on top? (sorry my bad english)

Comment: Argument of the `ShowDialog` method is a form, that will be the owner of a new form. This means that new form will be shown on top of its owner. (my english is bad too)