# How to hide or close second dialogbox before opening the third dialogbox without hiding/ closing main WinForm

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

Is it possible a C# form  to be modal without being dialogbox? Is there any alternatives to dialogbox. Because I think I cannot achieve what I want with dialogboxes. I have to (?) use dialogbox to make sure modality.

**First Edit:**

I have main Winform. From main Winform I want to produce a modal form like this

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

From the frm2 I want to open new modal form frm3, but I want to close frm2 before opening frm3.
I want to close open

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3();    
frm3.ShowDialog();
```

I want to close frm2 which is password dialog; as the user enters the correct password, I want to close frm2 and show advanced settings form which is frm3.

**Second Edit:**

One approach is hiding  the second frame before opening the third. But when I try

`this.Hide()`

in the second form, the first one also hid. Any solutions to hide only the second without the first? Or any other different solutions?

**Third Edit:**

Editing the title.

Comment: What do you mean by "modular"? And why don´t you want a dialog?

Comment: Who said forms are always _dialog boxes_?

Comment: Modular means you cannot edit or click other windows other than current. I want to create form from the current form and want to close current form. I cannot do this with dialogbox.

Comment: If your `current form` is the main form in `WinForm` then closing it will almost likely terminate the program. You can do it if you have three forms: one main, one the opened first-closed later, and one the closed-first opened later

Comment: @electro103 that's why I said you can't do that... you have to have *three* forms. Because once the main form is closed, the application is over...

Comment: Please use the description part of your question to describe what you're trying to do, is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: Hide the form before ShowDialog

Comment: I really don't understand. If from form2 you show form3 and then close form2, user is not even going to notice

Comment: @codroipo When I try this   this.Close(); the main Winform also hid. I want my main Winform not to be hidden.

Comment: See if this applies to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206340/c-sharp-show-dialog-over-another-dialog-in-winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand exactly the problem,but let's see if this is what you want to accomplish. You've got a main window, and want to show a login dialog and if the login is correct, show a settings dialog. This is how i would do it:

MainForm:

```
FormLogin login= new FormLogin();
if (login.ShowDialog() == true)
{
     FormSettings frmSett= new FormSettings();
     frmSett.ShowDialog();
}
```

FormLogin:

```
...
if (LoginOK)
{
     this.DialogResult = true;
}
else
{
     this.DialogResult = false;
}
this.Close();
...
```

Something like that. Hope that helps

Comment: I tried to open FormSettings() at the login window, and failed. So maybe the only way is to control everything from main.